# xcrun from XCTest on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xcrun

Is it possible to execute an `xcrun simctl` command from XCTest when targeting iOS?

This is possible when the target is macOS via `Process()`, but that doesn't exist for an iOS Test Host. And trying to dynamically load the class crashes the bundle.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm hoping to execute `xcrun simctl push` to test push notifications during a UI Test.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using SBTUITestTunnel

https://github.com/Subito-it/SBTUITestTunnelHost
https://github.com/Subito-it/SBTUITestTunnel

This tool allows running the shell command on the host device while running tests on your simulators.